# Validation, UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextfield

I am working on some simple form validation and need some assistance. Basically, I just need to make sure a `UITextField` doesn't have a '0' or no value whatsoever (nil) when a user runs a simple calculation. If the field does contain either/or a label will be changed to notify the user. Here is my statement:

```
if ([abc.text isEqualToString:@"0"] || [time.text isEqualToString:nil]) {
    self.123.text = @"Please enter a time";
} else {  whatever }
```

Currently the 123 label is outputting `NaN` if nothing is entered into the abc `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (![abc.text isEqualToString:@"0"]  &&
    ![time.text == nil]) 
    {
        self.123.text = @"Please enter a time";
    }
    else     
    { 
         whatever 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[time.text isEqualToString:nil]` with `[time.text isEqualToString:@""]`

You are trying to compare string with a nil object, and since a nil object (nil) is not the same as an empty string (@""), it fails.